# Which boon type does the feat "Deific Obedience" grant to non-prestige classes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In the sourcebook "Inner Sea Gods" there is a feat which grants the faithful an "Obedience" bonus after they perform a daily rite, depending on the god.

This feat also grants boons depending on hit dice:

> If you have at least 12 Hit Dice, you also gain the first boon granted by your diety upon undertaking your obedience. If you have at least 16 Hit Dice, you also gain the deity's second boon. If you have 20 Hit Dice or more you also gain the deity's third boon.

However in the book the books are split into three sections for the three prestige classes Evangelist, Exalted and Sentinel.

If a wizard takes the [Deific Obedience](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/deific-obedience) and is level 12 (and performs the daily obedience) which of the boons will they gain? Should this be chosen when the select the feat, or have I misread something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the feat description:

> If you have no levels in one of these prestige classes, you gain the
>   boons marked as **exalted** boons.

Comment: Gah, I read that twice, how did I miss that. Stupid brain!